# Deleting a record in a database table

Tags: c#, ms-access

I got problem when it comes to clicking the button assigned for deleting the record. Whenever I click it, it shows the **Microsoft Access Database Engine** in the message box but it doesn't delete the record.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = (@ "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GamefarmDB\GamefarmDB\Gamefarm.accdb;User ID = admin;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin; Persist Security Info=True;");

    String WingbandNumber = textBox1.Text;

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM List WHERE WingbandNumber ='" + WingbandNumber + "'", conn);

    conn.Open();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WingbandNumber", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = WingbandNumber;

        try {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");
            conn.Close();
            this.Close();
        } catch (OleDbException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
            conn.Close();
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `WHERE WingbandNumber ='" + WingbandNumber + "'"` be `WHERE WingbandNumber = @WingbandNumber"`?

Comment: I have tried it and it showed "System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: I imagine it would have given you an error message too.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6444/using-oledb-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-2007-file may be of interest.

Answer (score -1):

I've figured it out anyways thank you for your help! I changed the database command into

```
("DELETE FROM List WHERE WingbandNumber =" + WingbandNumber, conn);
```

Comment: Very bad idea since this leaves you open to SQL injection. *Always* use parameterized queries. If you have issues with `WHERE WingbandNumber = @WingbandNumber` then you need to fix those, as this certainly works.